# How to use jQuery autocomplete to search particular record ignoring the order words entered in input box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angular, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete in my Angular 2 rc4.

My Html is `<input class="search" id="search-input" type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Search by keyword, lesson or standard" #searchResult1  [(ngModel)]="completeMe"/>`

in .ts file

```
heroes:any=[];
this.heroes.push(
{
    "id": "1",
    "label": "This is example text"
});
 this.heroes.push(
{
    "id": "2",
    "label": "This is result text"
});
jQuery('#search-input')
  .autocomplete({
    source:this.heroes,
    minLength: 2,
 });
```

Result ::
When i am entered 'this is' in i/p box, then both result will append in li tag.
and when i enter 'this result' then nothing will shown or append in li tag.

Expected Result : 
When i enter 'this result' or 'result this' , then it should append 'This is result text' in li tag ignoring the order of text entered.

currently it is only rendering exact match from the sentence. but i wanted to ignore order of words.

Please Help.

Comment: Should be pretty easy by creating custom matcher for `source` option used as a function. There will be a regex that matches words in any order.

Comment: @dfsq can you please guide me where i can get the documentation to create custom matcher . or tell me how to assign regex to source !

Comment: Here it is http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: @dfsq Thanks a lot. I will go through it, but it will be great if you post code for how to create custom matcher for source and use it in my above scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
jQuery('#search-input')
  .autocomplete({
    source: (request, response) => {
      const val = '^(?=.*\\b' + request.term.trim().split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$'
      const matcher = RegExp(val, 'i')

      response(this.heroes.filter(item => matcher.test(item.label)));
    },
    minLength: 2,
  });
```

Also note, you should not use `jQuery('#search-input')`, consider using `elementRef.nativeElement` of corresponding component or query DOM within this component, but not globally like you are doing now.